# React Conditional Rendering

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, conditional-rendering

I'm trying to figure out conditional rendering in React. If there are no movies in the user's watchlist, i just want to output a title. I thought somethin like this would work:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            {this.state.watchlist.map(item => {
                if(this.state.watchlist.length > 0) {
                    return (
                        <WatchlistMovie
                            className="watchlist-movie"
                            key={item.id}
                            id={item.id}
                            title={item.title}
                            poster={item.poster}
                            overview={item.overview}
                            rating={item.rating}
                            user={this.props.user}
                        />
                    );
                } else {
                    return <h1>no movies</h1>
                }
            )}}
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is this not working? Are you getting errors?

Comment: I believe you want the `if-else` logic outsides of the `map`

Comment: @Vencovsky No errors, just dont get the <h1> tag displayed if there are no movies in the watchlist

Comment: What is the <Container /> in your application? Is it set up to display this.props.children?

Comment: <Container> is a component from react-bootstrap <Container/> read more about it here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you want the `if-else` logic outsides of the `map`

```
  <Container>
    {this.state.watchlist.length === 0 && <h1>no movies</h1>}

    {this.state.watchlist.map(item => (<WatchlistMovie
      className="watchlist-movie"
      key={item.id}
      id={item.id}
      title={item.title}
      poster={item.poster}
      overview={item.overview}
      rating={item.rating}
      user={this.props.user}
    />))}

  </Container>
```

Comment: i get the logic of your answer, but it still seems not to be working for me, and i get no errors. If i check the React Dev tools, i can see the <h1> tag, however its greyed out.

Comment: @juicyj Then  the problem is somewhere else. Because the second operand of `&&` would only be executed if the first it truthy (which is of course not in case of an empty array)

Comment: got it, seems like bootstrap was being weird and hiding my element, thanks again Yury!

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem in your code, which is that you check `this.state.watchlist.length > 0` inside `this.state.watchlist.map`, and that you want to display the `h1` element when the `length` is equal to `0`.
The problem is that `map()` function iterates over all the elements of an array, and, if the array is empty, no callback is executed.

Thus, in your case, when `this.state.watchlist.length` is equal to `0`, you don't even enter the `map()` function, so you can't render the `h1` element at all.

As many user suggested, you should change your render method:

```
render() {
    const movieCounter = this.state.watchlist.length;
    return (
        <Container>
            {movieCounter === 0
                ? <h1>no movies</h1>
                : this.state.watchlist.map(item =>
                    <WatchlistMovie
                        className="watchlist-movie"
                        key={item.id}
                        id={item.id}
                        title={item.title}
                        poster={item.poster}
                        overview={item.overview}
                        rating={item.rating}
                        user={this.props.user}
                    />
                )}
            }
        </Container>
    );
}
```

In this example, what is happening is that you check if `movieCounter` is equal to `0`: in that case, you display the `h1` element, otherwise you iterate over all the films and display a `WatchlistMovie` Component for each one of them.

Comment: i get this logic as well, however just like with Yurys answer it seems to not be working for me either, and i get no errors. If i check the React Dev tools, i can see the <h1> tag, however its greyed out.

Comment: Can you explain me better what you mean with "greyed out"? Anyways, can you also post the `Container` implementation?

Comment: You're welcome. Though, try to explain what was the problem: some other users may end up in this question and need your answer too :)

Comment: My issue was that React-Bootstrap was hiding my element off the page for some reason, i just had to add margin top so the title was visible on my webpage. Both your code and Yury's worked flawlessly! thanks again :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use what we call `short circuit` evaluation for conditional rendering in React.

```
render() {
return (
  <Container>

    {this.state.watchlist.length > 0 && (this.state.watchlist.map(item => {
      <WatchlistMovie
        className="watchlist-movie"
        key={item.id}
        id={item.id}
        title={item.title}
        poster={item.poster}
        overview={item.overview}
        rating={item.rating}
        user={this.props.user}
      />)}
    {this.state.watchlist.length === 0 && (
       <h1>no movies</h1>)
     }
  </Container>

);
}
}
```

In this type of expression if the first condition is `true` then the component will after it will be rendered otherwise it will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

There is alot of ways to do this, this example shows how to do it using ternary.
I think this is a better looking and smallert code, but you can also use Yury Tarabanko answer that do the same

```
render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        {this.state.watchlist.length > 0 ?
            this.state.watchlist.map(item => 
                <WatchlistMovie
                    className="watchlist-movie"
                    key={item.id}
                    id={item.id}
                    title={item.title}
                    poster={item.poster}
                    overview={item.overview}
                    rating={item.rating}
                    user={this.props.user}
                />
            })
            :
            <h1>no movies</h1>            
        }
      </Container>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!