# React JS how would I render an alert inside of a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a login page and I want to display an error if the login fails.
I call the function here: onClick={ this.login }
But I want the function to display the error message without re-rendering everything. The function is inside a class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Conditional Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263341/react-conditional-rendering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it by creating an invisible alert that's visible when I set a variable to the error

```
         {
          this.state.status && 
          <Alert severity="error">
            <AlertTitle>Error</AlertTitle>
            { this.state.status }
          </Alert>
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
const [error, setError] = useState('');

const handleLogin = async () => {
  // request a login to your server
  const res = await fetch('http://yourapi.com/login');
  // determine if the request was successful
  if (res.error) {
    setError('Invalid input.')
  }
  else {
    // continue
  }
};

return (
  <Form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
     <span>{error}</span>
     <input onChangeText={text => setUsername(text)}/>
  </Form>
);
```